# Android TextView with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, textview

I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>Displaying maths</title> </head> <body> $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$ </body> </html>
```

And I want to display the result in an Android TextView. I tried to use `Html.fromHtml()` but don't work.

it's: http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

Comment: try with web view as you have scripts in it